# Value Error is Titanic dataset in the pandas library

Tags: dataset

Int this my problem in titanic dataset on work and find to corelation between the columns

but rasied value error is:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris'
```

I will trying to corelation between in the columns but facing problem is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Datasets/train.csv')
df.corr()
```

but rasied the value error is:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris'
```